# React Redux Connect MapState not updating for a filtered item from a collection

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I think I've either misunderstood something, or am doing something deeply wrong, when attempting to subscribe to changes on a specific item in a collection in my store.  Unless I add a direct list subscription, my component does not receive updates.

The following works:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => ({
  list: state.podcasts.items,
  getItem: props.id
    ? state.podcasts.items.filter(item => item.clientId === props.id)[0] || {}
    : {},
});
```

If I remove the list item I only receive the the initial state of the collection item I'm subscribing to.

How I'm updating the list in the reducer:

```
PODCAST_GRADIENT_UPDATED: (state, { payload }) => ({
    ...state,
    items: state.items.map(item => {
      if (item.clientId === payload.clientId) {
        item.gradient = payload.gradient; // eslint-disable-line
      }
      return item;
    }),
  }),
```

- Should the above work without the list subscription?
- if not, how should this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this was a rookie error, in that there is some state mutation in the above example.   changing my function in the reducer in the following way resolved this:

```
PODCAST_GRADIENT_UPDATED: (state, { payload }) => ({
    ...state,
    items: state.items.map(item => {
      if (item.clientId === payload.clientId) {
        return { ...item, gradient: payload.gradient };
      }
      return { ...item };
    }),
  }),
```

notice specifically the use of the spread operator to create and return a new item.